# "Setup" meaning "beginning"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning, word-in-context

I would like to know if I can use the word "setup" with the meaning of "beginning" in these sentences:

> 1. From the setup and until the end of the process you will be seeing changes made to this document.
> 2. The setup of the drama reveals to us a night scene where a young woman sits on grass and looks up into the starry sky.

If not, what word would you recommend that I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In number 1, it technically makes sense, but the most common word choice would be "start". In this context, you can also drop that prepositional phrase altogether, because it is implied by the rest of the sentence. I'd phrase it like this:

"By the end of the process you will see changes made to this document."

In number 2, it makes more sense. The "setup" in this context is more clear because it is referring to how the author is creating (or "setting up") the plot of the drama. The only change I'd make is the word "reveales":

"The setup of the drama *depicts* a night scene *where* a young woman sits on grass and looks up into the starry sky."

Comment: Sorry... I meant to say that "You will be seeing changes throughout the process". And "were" instead of "where" is a T9 auto-correct replacement )))

Comment: Ah okay. "You will be seeing changes throughout the process" makes sense, but "You will see changes throughout the process" would be better. "To be" + verb + ing is the "future continuous" tense. It implies an ongoing action. That may be what you are going for, but the prepositional phrase "throughout the process" already implies that it's continuous. It is a bit awkward to have both. I'd either say "You will be seeing changes" or, ideally, "You will see see changes throughout the process."

Comment: I guess you're right!

Answer (score 2):

According to definitions, [*setup*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/setup) in your context primarily refers to:

> *noun*
>   1. the way in which something is *set up*; specif.,
>   a. the plan, makeup, or arrangement, as of equipment, an organization, etc.
>   b. the details of a situation, plan of action, etc.

It does not mean *beginning*, although the "setup" step could be the beginning of a specified process or activity.